# Property binding not updating

Tags: qt, binding, qml, qtquick2, qtcpsocket

I am continuously getting data for my application as it runs, but I am having a bit of trouble displaying the data once I have read it in and stored it in a map.

When I try to display the data in the QML, it simply displays zero, despite the fact that I can see it updating in the application output.

I access the value in QML using property bindings (I was under the impression that these led `headingSensor` to be updated whenever `carData.headingSensor` changed?):

```
property int headingSensor: carData.headingSensor
Text {  text: "Heading: " + headingSensor }
```

---

In my data class I have:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int headingSensor READ getHeadingSensor NOTIFY headingSensorChanged)
        int headingSensor;
```

---

In the c++ implementation I originally had:

```
    int data::getHeadingSensor(){
        return data.value(heading)[headingSensorReading];
    }
```

---

Where it returns the value in the map which is being updated with the incoming information.

This I realized, probably doesn’t work, because the property is dependent upon the headingSensor variable, which is itself not being updated despite the correct value being returned. So, I thought if I changed it to update the headingSensor value and return that it might work.

So in my data aquisition logic I wrote a method to update the variables as well.

```
                data.insert(key, value);
                updateVariables();
            }
        }
    }
    void data::updateVariables(){
        headingSensor = data.value(heading)[headingSensorReading];
    }
    int data::getHeadingSensor(){
        return headingSensor;
    }
```

While this led to the `headingSensor` variable being updated in addition to the value in the map, the correct value is still not displayed in the QML display. It simply displays `0` (its default value when it is initially displayed since it has not gotten a value from incoming data yet).

So, I am wondering, how can I get the value of sensorHeading displayed in the QML to update as the value of it and/or the value in the map changes in C++? Do I need to do something like:

```
Connections {
    target: carData
    onSensorHeadingChanged: updateValues
}
```

EDIT:
Trying something like this, the onSensorHeadingChanged never fires. I am not sure why, since the value of sensorHeading clearly changes as I watch it in the application output

---

```
Connections{
     target: carData
     onHeadingSensorChanged: console.log("It's noting the change!")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is the responsibility of the C++ element writer to emit `headingSensorChanged()` in order to cause the binding to be updated.

[This tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-extending-tutorial-index.html) is a good place to start when implementing a C++ element.

In your case you need to do something like this:

```
void data::updateVariables(){
    int sensorReading = data.value(heading)[headingSensorReading];
    if (headingSensor != sensorReading) {
        headingSensor = sensorReading;
        emit headingSensorChanged();
    }
}
```

Note that we don't emit the change notifier unless there really is a change.  This prevents needless JS evaluations, and also removes the possibility of binding loops.

Comment: Ah! I am a fool! Thank you so much. I was so used to writing elements that had getters and setters (which emitted the Changed signal), that when I was writing this where the socket updates the information, I did not think to put in the emit signal. Thanks a million!